# Changing Parameters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

I am trying to plot three different functions into one plot, an approximate solution to an ODE, an exact solution to the ODE and the relative error. My function is only outputting one of these graphs. I am unsure how to plot all three at once and how to change the parameters for k so that It plots k at .02, .1 and 1.5.

I have this function in a separate file. This is the approximate solution:

```
function dydt = prblm1_fun(t,y)
k = 0.02
if t < 1
dydt = y(1)*k + sin(pi*t);
elseif t < 2
dydt = y(1)*k + 0.5;
else
dydt=y(1)*k + exp(t-2)/2;
end
```

This function is attempting to solve the approximate and plot the three.

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@prblm1_fun,[0 2.5],0);
plot(T,Y)
k=0.02;

for i =1:length(T)
if  T(i) < 1
y_exact(i) = 1/(k^2+pi^2)*(pi*exp(k*T(i))-pi*cos(pi*T(i))-    k*sin(pi*T(i)));
elseif T(i) < 2
y_exact(i) = 1/2/k*(exp(k*(T(i)-1))-1) + pi/(k^2+pi^2)*(exp(k*T(i)) +      exp(k*(T(i)-1)));
else
y_exact(i) = 1/2/k*(exp(k*(T(i)-1))-exp(k*(T(i)-2))) + pi/(k^2+pi^2)(exp(k*T(i)) + exp(k*(T(i)-1))) + 1/2/(k-1)*(exp(k*(T(i)-2)) - exp(T(i)-2));
end
end


rel_error = (y_exact - Y')./y_exact
```

Where am i going wrong and how do I change the parameters of k in a single graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set k serious values, you may put it into the ode function as parameter.

When you define the function:

```
function dydt = prblm1_fun(t,y,k)
```

When you call the ode function:

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@(t,y) prblm1_fun(t, y,k), [0 2.5],0)
```

For now, you can use a for loop to set the value of k and do the plot.

Is this your question?